# How to prove sorted list

Tags: coq

```
Fixpoint index_value (i: nat) (j: nat) (l: list nat) : nat :=
match l with
| nil => 0
| cons h t => match (eqb i j) with
| true => h
| false => index_value (S i) j t
  end
  end.

   index1 < index2
   1 index_value  0 (S index2) (n' :: l) <= n'.

   2 index_value  0 index2 (n' :: l) <=
     index_value  0 (S index1) (n' :: l) 
   In hypothesis I have
   H1 : (length l =? 0) = false
   H2 : 0 < S index2
   H3 : forall (l : list nat) (d : nat),
   descending l ->
    forall m : nat, In m l -> m <= hd d l.
```

I am using the above function to find different values in natural number list. I can find any value in the list by changing index j and by keeping i=0.index_value 0 0 [n::t]=n and it is greatest,because of 
 descending order. Any other value in the list,found by changing 
 j,should be lower than n. Want to prove these two 
  cases .Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: What are the things you tried? Do you why you are stuck? Perhaps you could show the lemma you're trying to prove?

Comment: You should write one lemma in the post, tell clearly why you are stuck, what you tried.

Comment: Lemma maxl_prop:
forall l n h,
In n l -> n  <=h. Found the maximum value from the list and assigned this value to the head of the list.Stuck because ,unable to prove that value at S(index2)<= index1

Comment: Lemma maxl_prop: forall l n h, In n l -> n <=maxl m l..While maxl l is a function that requires two inputs( nat and l)  and give highest value as output.

Answer (score 1):

I am glad that you reformulate your question @laibanaz.
Your lemma now is just a stronger version of the previous lemma which you proposed in your last [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61153115/maximum-elelment-in-the-list/61219564#61219564).

For example, knowing that all values are equal/less than the maximum value of the list and thus, any value of an nth tail of some list as well :

```
Fixpoint taill {A} (x : nat) (ls : list A) : list A := 
  match x with
    |S n => match ls with
             |k :: u => taill n u
             |[] => []
            end
    |0 => ls
  end.

Theorem maxValue_tail : forall ls y (H : [] <> ls) n, In n (taill y ls) -> n <= maxvalue H.
```

You should be able to get :

```
(* your lemma probably will need a way of checking the index boundaries, so I put this additional checking*)
Theorem sorting_leb_order : forall (l : list nat) k k',
   descending l -> k' < length l -> k < length l -> k <= k -> 
      index_value k' l <= index_value k l.
```

Just relying on the fact that any (descending) sorted list, the head is the maximum value and getting an index of some list, is just the head of some nth list.

```
(* the j second index is really necessary? *)
Fixpoint index_value (i: nat) (l: list nat) : nat :=
  match l with
    | nil => 0
    | cons h t => 
      match (Nat.eqb i 0) with
       | true => h
       | false => index_value (i - 1) t
      end
  end.

Definition hd A (ls : list A) : [] <> ls -> A :=
   match ls return [] <> ls -> A with
    |x :: xs => fun H => x 
    |[] => fun H => match (H eq_refl) with end
 end.

Theorem maxl_prop : forall (l : list nat) (H : [] <> l),
   descending l -> maxvalue H = hd H. 

(* the index of some value is the head of nth tail *)
Theorem index_taill : forall (ls : list nat) k (H : [] <> (taill k ls)),
   index_value k ls = hd H.

(* We'll need a way of getting a In preposition of some index value *)
Theorem index_InBound : forall k k' l, k' < length l -> k <= k' -> 
   In (index_value k' l) (taill k l).

Theorem inToIndex : forall (ls : list nat) k, k < length ls -> In (index_value k ls) ls
```

Now, we just have to prove sorting_leb_order rewriting the lemma with the theorems above (the others theorems is avaiable in your last [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61153115/maximum-elelment-in-the-list/61219564#61219564))   :

```
Theorem sorting_leb_order : forall (l : list nat) k k',
   descending l -> k' < length l -> k < length l -> k <= k' -> 
       index_value k' l <= index_value k l.

   intros.
   destruct (destruct_list (taill k l)).
   do 2! destruct s.
   have : ~ [] =  taill k l. rewrite e; done.
   move => H'.
   (*rewrite the definitions*)
   pose (inToIndex H0).
   rewrite (index_taill H'); rewrite <- maxl_prop.
   by apply : maxValue; apply : index_InBound.
   clear i e x0 H0 H1.
   move : H.
   (* cut a sorted listed produces a cutted list sorted *)
   unfold descending.
   elim/@taill_scheme : (taill k l).
   intros; assumption.
   intros; assumption.
   intros; apply : H; simpl in H0.
   destruct u.
   exact I.
   (*bound checking *)
   by case : H0.
     have : False.
      elim/@taill_scheme : (taill k l) H1 e.
      intros; subst.
      inversion H1.
      intros; inversion H1.
      intros; apply : H1. 
      auto with arith.
      trivial.
   move => //=.
Qed.
```

I proposed a definition of sorting preposition, but you can prove the correspondence of your preposition without problems. 
 The lemma is not necessarily hard but can grow very fast, it depends on what kind of definitions are you using. In that case, once you preferred working with an unbound index version(it's better working with [Fin](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Vectors.Fin.html)) the lemma is a little more challenger, first because of the edge cases, and second, because doing induction with indexes needs more specified schemes. Unfortunately the ... lemma becomes a little big, therefore I wasn't able to post the full proof here but you can get [here](https://gist.github.com/caotic123/7aba9a1cc9b9112a9e6f84dfae14dbe9)).

Comment: pose (inToIndex H0).  The reference inToIndex
was not found in the current
environment.

Comment: It's the lemma inToIndex : forall (ls : list nat) k, k < length ls -> In (index_value k ls) ls, get here (https://gist.github.com/caotic123/7aba9a1cc9b9112a9e6f84dfae14dbe9)

Comment: Thanks for help.I am not setting the boundries,therefore facing problem. For  clarification ,I am asking these question 1.Our lemma is based on that  index1 < index2 a

Comment: 3.  k <= k', In index_InBound lemma, which should be k<k'.Because two indexes cannot be equal.4.Instead of  maxvalue function ,we can use our maxl n l function,which will give maximum value from list?

Comment: Lemma index1_2 : forall (index1 index2 :nat),
(S index1 =? index2) = false ->
 S index1 < 1->
 index2 < 1 ->
(index2 <= S index1). we can close this goal by applying hypothesis ( false=false). for 1<1.

Comment: When k = k', it's just a trivial case that states reflexivity. You can easily derive a lemma k < k' -> index k' list <= index k list, it's just a corollary, you just have to state the new lemma and uses the main proof